# How to write {ARCHITECTURE} ="7-M" in GNU GCC assembler

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, gnu-assembler, keil

What will be the syntax to write `{ARCHITECTURE} = "7-M"` in GNU syntax using `-march` and `arm7`?

I am importing Keil-based  assembly code in GCC assembly code.

Answer (score 1):

You said you are importing into GCC (compiler) but I presume you mean GAS (assembler).

You can find in the [GAS manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html) the the `.arch` directive.

```
.arch armv7-m
```